# Excel formula to sort data based on unique individuals?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

I have approx 29,000 rows of data and three columns: a unique ID, an admission date and a departure date

[image: See image for extract]

I need to sort the data so that:

1) The admission dates are in order from newest to oldest for **each individual** ID (i.e. the admin dates associated ONLY with the ID 455 are ordered from newest to oldest and then start again and do the same thing with ID 677 and 899 etc.); and

2) The departure date associated with each admin date stay locked together.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how I might go about achieving it?

Thanks so much advance!

Comment: Sure, depending on language: SQL? PLSQL? See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the built-in menu features in Excel (2016 for example):

- **Select *all*** of the data in all 3 columns
- Choose the '**Sort**' function under the 'Data' tab.

[image: Excel 2016 Data >> Sort]

- Check the "**My data has headers**" box
- Under 'Column', select "**Sort by: ID**" and verify 'Order' is "**Smallest to Largest**"

[image: Excel 2016 Sort Part I.]

- Press the 'Add Level' button
- Under 'Column', select "**Then by: Admission Date**" and verify 'Order' is <s>"Oldest to Newest"</s> "**Newest to Oldest**"
- Press the 'OK' button

[image: Excel 2016 Sort Part II.]

That should do it.
Older/newer versions of Excel also have this 'Sort' functionality although the interface & menus may be slightly different.

*To accomplish this with a **formula** (as the question mentions), some complex usage of 'VLOOKUP()' could work...*

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic approach, you can build a Pivot Table. Drag ID, Admission Date and Departure date into the rows area. Use a tabular layout and don't show subtotals (these options are on the Design ribbon of the Pivot Table Tools).

Pivot tables automatically sort data ascending. Here is a quick example.

When new data is added to the source table, you just need to refresh the pivot table.

[image]